# how to test if component rerenders after state change for react hooks testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

I'm using https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library to test my component but not sure how to check if my component has been re-rendered after a state change in this test

```
const { container, getAllByText, getAllByRole, queryByLabelText, getByText, getByLabelText } = renderNavBar(
    initialState,
    dispatchMock,
);

// get all divs
let divs = getAllByRole('div');
.
.
.

const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useReducer(Reducer, initialState));
const [ , dispatch ] = result.current;

act(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_ACTIVE_LINK', payload: 'about' });
    fireEvent.click(getByText('home'));
});


// get all divs after the state change,
divs = getAllByRole('div');  // <---- this still has the NavBar component with the old state
```

The state successfully updates after the dispatch/click event. I want to be able to get the component re-rendered with new state but it's still showing the original component with the previous state

Comment: Typically you need to wait for the UI to update, check [async](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet#async). Also, check out [user events](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event), it handles using events a little better than the baked in generic fire event.

Comment: so you shouldn't explicitly have to call rerender with the new state? the component should just rerender automatically after the state changes?

Comment: No, I wouldn't think you would need to rerender anything forcefully. Also, looks like the docs I linked earlier are out-of-date, the underlying DOM testing library async [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async) are a little more informative. Some functionality has been deprecated it seems.

Comment: I was writing up a test application for myself and ran into a similar issue. I had to forcefully re-render the application in order to get the UI to show an update. Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67551015/6534074

Answer (score 0):

```
await const divs = findAllByRole('div');
```

findAllBy is async and will wait to find it.
findAll will throw an error if it doesn't find the value. https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/