# React Testing Library's waitFor not working

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am using [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#2-using-waitfor) to unit test my ReactJS code. There are several async events in the UI, like fetching data and displaying a new page on click of button. The React code is somewhat like this:

```
// Inside ParentComponent.tsx
const [isChildVisible, setChildVisibility] = useState(false);
const showChild = () => setChildVisibility(true);

return(
  <>
      <button data-testid="show-child" onClick={showChild}>Show Child</button>
      {isChildVisible && <ChildComponent {..childProps}/>}
 </>
)
```

Where `ChildComponent` mounts, it fetches some data and then re-renders itself with the hydrated data. My unit test looks like:

```
jest.mock('../../../src/service'); // mock the fetch functions used by ChildComponent to fetch its data

describe('ParentComponent', () => {
    test('renders ChildComponent on button click', async () => {
        const screen = render(<ParentComponent />);
        userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('show-child'));
        await (waitFor(() => screen.getByText('text rendered by child')));
    });
});
```

When I run this test, I get the error `"TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: text rendered by child. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible."`.

I am not sure why it's happening, but one of the reason maybe that it's taking more than one second to hydrate and render the child component. Thus I want to change the default wait time for `waitFor`, but I can't find a way to do it from the docs (the default wait time is one second). So is it possible to change the default wait time?

EDIT: Increasing the wait time is still causing the same error. So the issue is something else.

Answer (score 30):

I found the answer here: [React Testing Library - using 'await wait()' after fireEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062395/react-testing-library-using-await-wait-after-fireevent)

TLDR: "You can not use wait with getBy*. getBy is not async and will not wait." Better is to use findBy*. This is the async version of getBy.

Comment: Oh man, feels like I ran into this before and now I'm running into it again. If it weren't for your answer I'd be down the same rabbit hole.

Comment: docs state differently https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#2-using-waitfor

Answer (score 16):

It's specified within the documentation. [waitFor Documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)

```
function waitFor<T>(
  callback: () => T | Promise<T>,
  options?: {
     container?: HTMLElement
     timeout?: number //This is 1000ms. Change timeout here.
     interval?: number
     onTimeout?: (error: Error) => Error
     mutationObserverOptions?: MutationObserverInit
  }
): Promise<T>

//For 3 seconds.
await (waitFor(() => screen.getByText('text rendered by child'),{timeout:3000}));
```

The default timeout is 1000ms which will keep you under Jest's default timeout of 5000ms.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow missed it. But unfortunately, increasing the wait time is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 7):

I had an issue similar to this when I was setting up testing for a test application. The way I fixed this issue was to force re-render the component.

In this case your code would look something like:

```
import {render, screen} from "@testing-library/react";

describe('ParentComponent', () => {
  test('renders ChildComponent on button click', async () => {

    const {rerender} = render(<ParentComponent />);
    userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('show-child'));

    rerender(<ParentComponent />)
    await (waitFor(() => screen.getByText('text rendered by child')));
  });
});
```

I hope this works for you. Also to be noted that you can use the `screen` export from the react testing library. It seems like there should be a way to do this automatically, but I haven't been able to find it.

Adding link to the rerender docs: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#rerender

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using `jest-expo` preset which breaks this functionality you need to modify the `jest-expo` preset to include the code from `testing-library/react-native`

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const { mergeDeepRight } = require("ramda");
const jestExpoPreset = require("jest-expo/jest-preset");
const testingLibraryPreset = require("@testing-library/react-native/jest-preset");

/*
 * Modify the existing jest preset to implement the fix of @testing-library/react-native to get the
 * async waitFor working with modern timers.
 */
jestExpoPreset.setupFiles = [
  testingLibraryPreset.setupFiles[0],
  ...jestExpoPreset.setupFiles,
  testingLibraryPreset.setupFiles[testingLibraryPreset.setupFiles.length - 1],
];
module.exports = mergeDeepRight(jestExpoPreset, {
  testResultsProcessor: "jest-sonar-reporter",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "yml"],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/lib/"],
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      babelConfig: "./babel.config.js",
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `screen.queryByText(/pattern/)` it works inside the waitFor fucntion.